# How to add data from controller to a blade file in laravel for table?

Tags: html, laravel

I am trying to add data for a table from mysql to laravel blade file and the data is adding row by row, but i need the data to be entered in a single row.
[image]

Here is my vscode(oneway.blade.php) file.I used for each and if else to display the data to the table.
[image].

I used foreach to get the data from RatesController.php file.[image].

[image]

I need to display the rates as a single row like this.[image]

I tried to get all the data in a single row. But the data was adding one by one row wise. I used `foreach` to get the data from RatesController.php to my blade file oneway.blade.php file.

```
@foreach($rates as $rate)
@foreach($dummies as $dummy)

              if($dummy->passenger_category_name_start_value == $rate->passenger_category_name_start_value) 
    
                <td class="location">{{$rate->places_id_start}}</td>
                <td class="location">{{$rate->places_id_destination}}</td>
              
              
                  <td class="price">
    
                  
                        @if ($rate->passenger_category_name_start_value == 1)
    
                          € {{$rate->rate}}
    
                        @elseif ($rate->passenger_category_name_end_value <= 3)
    
                          € {{$rate->rate}}
                            
                        @endif
                  
                  
                  </td>
                
              
                <td class="price">
    
                  @if ($rate->passenger_category_name_start_value == 4)
    
                    € {{$rate->rate}}
    
                  @elseif ($rate->passenger_category_name_end_value <= 5)
    
                    €
                      
                  @endif
    
    
                </td>
    
                <td class="price">
    
    
                  @if ($rate->passenger_category_name_start_value == 5)
    
                    € {{$rate->rate}}
    
                  @elseif ($rate->passenger_category_name_end_value <= 6)
    
                    €
                      
                  @endif
    
                </td>
    
                <td class="price">
    
    
                  @if ($rate->passenger_category_name_start_value == 6)
    
                    € {{$rate->rate}}
    
                  @elseif ($rate->passenger_category_name_end_value <= 6)
    
                    €
                      
                  @endif          
    
    
                </td>
    
                <td class="price">
    
    
                  @if ($rate->passenger_category_name_start_value == 7)
    
                    € {{$rate->rate}}
    
                  @elseif ($rate->passenger_category_name_end_value <= 7)
    
                    €
                      
                  @endif
    
    
                </td>
    
                <td class="price">
    
    
                  @if ($rate->passenger_category_name_start_value == 8)
    
                    € {{$rate->rate}}
    
                  @elseif ($rate->passenger_category_name_end_value <= 9)
    
                    €
                      
                  @endif
    
    
                </td>
    
                <td class="price">
    
    
                  @if ($rate->passenger_category_name_start_value == 9)
    
                    € {{$rate->rate}}
    
                  @elseif ($rate->passenger_category_name_end_value <= 10)
    
                    €
                      
                  @endif
    
    
                </td>
    
                <td class="price">
    
    
                @if ($rate->passenger_category_name_start_value == 10)
    
                  € {{$rate->rate}}
    
                @elseif ($rate->passenger_category_name_end_value <= 11)
    
                  €
                    
                @endif
    
                <td class="price">
    
    
                @if ($rate->passenger_category_name_start_value == 11)
    
                  € {{$rate->rate}}
    
                @elseif ($rate->passenger_category_name_end_value <= 12)
    
                  €
    
                @endif
    
    
                </td>
    
                <td class="price">
    
    
                @if ($rate->passenger_category_name_start_value == 12)
    
                  € {{$rate->rate}}
    
                @elseif ($rate->passenger_category_name_end_value <= 13)
    
                  €
                    
                @endif
    
    
                </td>
    
                <td class="price">
    
    
                @if ($rate->passenger_category_name_start_value == 13)
    
                  € {{$rate->rate}}
    
                @elseif ($rate->passenger_category_name_end_value <= 14)
    
                  €
                    
                @endif
    
    
                </td>
    
                <td class="price">
    
    
                @if ($rate->passenger_category_name_start_value == 14)
    
                  € {{$rate->rate}}
    
                @elseif ($rate->passenger_category_name_end_value <= 15)
    
                  €
                    
                @endif
    
                </td>
    
                <td class="price">
    
    
                @if ($rate->passenger_category_name_start_value == 15)
    
                  € {{$rate->rate}}
    
                @elseif ($rate->passenger_category_name_end_value <= 16)
    
                  €
                  
                @endif
    
    
                </td>
    
                <td class="price">
    
    
                @if ($rate->passenger_category_name_start_value == 16)
    
                  € {{$rate->rate}}
    
                @else
    
                  €
                    
                @endif
    
    
                </td>
    
    
    
              </tr>
              
            @endforeach
          @endforeach
```

[image]

I used for each in controller RatesController.php to get from my backend file.

```
<?php

  
namespace App\\Http\\Controllers\\Frontend;  
use App\\Http\\Controllers\\Controller;

use App\\Models\\TourCategories;

use App\\Models\\PassengerCategories;

use App\\Models\\Rates;use App\\Models\\Place;

class RatesController extends Controller

{

    $rates =  Rates::where('deleted','=','0')->orderBy('rates.id')->get();
    
            // dd($rates);
    
            foreach($rates as $rate){
    
                $place = Place::where('id','=',$rate['places_id_start'])->first();
                $rate['places_id_start'] = $place['name'];
            }
    
            foreach($rates as $rate){
    
                $place = Place::where('id','=',$rate['places_id_destination'])->first();
                $rate['places_id_destination'] = $place['name'];
            }
    
            foreach($rates as $rate){
    
                $passenger_category = PassengerCategories::where('id','=',$rate['pasenger_categories_id'])->first();
                $rate['passenger_category_name_start_value'] = $passenger_category['start_value'];
            }
            foreach($rates as $rate){
    
                $passenger_category = PassengerCategories::where('id','=',$rate['pasenger_categories_id'])->first();
                $rate['passenger_category_name_end_value'] = $passenger_category['end_value'];
            }
            //dd($rates);
            //return $rates;
    
            $dummies =  Rates::where('deleted','=','0')->orderBy('rates.id')->get();
    
            // dd($rates);
    
            foreach($dummies as $dummy){
    
                $place = Place::where('id','=',$dummy['places_id_start'])->first();
                $dummy['places_id_start'] = $place['name'];
            }
    
            foreach($dummies as $dummy){
    
                $place = Place::where('id','=',$dummy['places_id_destination'])->first();
                $dummy['places_id_destination'] = $place['name'];
            }
    
            //dd($dummies);
            
    
            
    
    
            $tourCategories = TourCategories::where('active',1)->where('deleted',0)->get();
            return view('frontend.rates.oneway',compact('tourCategories','rates','dummies'));
    
            // dd($tourCategories);
        }
        public function paris(){
            $tourCategories = TourCategories::where('active',1)->where('deleted',0)->get();
            return view('frontend.transfers.paristransfers',compact('tourCategories'));
            //dd($tourCategories);
        }
```

Comment: Please post the code instead of screenshots as we cannot reproduce this with screenshots

Answer (score 0):

In oneway.blade.php on line 57 you need to prepend the if statement with an @

Comment: yes thank you i add @ ...  @if($dummy->passenger_category_name_start_value == $rate->passenger_category_name_start_value) . but still the data is not passing to the table..

Comment: There are many more errors in the code.

You only need one foreach for rates. rather than 4.

Objects should be accessed via arrow notation rather than arrays. IE $place['name'] should be $place->name

You should use eloquent relationships to get places and passengers rather than additional db calls.

Your use statements contain double \\ i'm not sure why. It should be use App\Models\Rates; Are your models actually in a folder called models? They shouldn't be

Answer (score 0):

Check this code:

@foreach($rates as $rate)
@foreach($dummies as $dummy)

```
          @if($dummy->passenger_category_name_start_value == $rate->passenger_category_name_start_value) 

            <td class="location">{{$rate->places_id_start}}</td>
            <td class="location">{{$rate->places_id_destination}}</td>
          
          
              <td class="price">

              
                    @if ($rate->passenger_category_name_start_value == 1)

                      € {{$rate->rate}}

                    @elseif ($rate->passenger_category_name_end_value <= 3)

                      € {{$rate->rate}}
                        
                    @endif
              
              
              </td>
            
          
            <td class="price">

              @if ($rate->passenger_category_name_start_value == 4)

                € {{$rate->rate}}

              @elseif ($rate->passenger_category_name_end_value <= 5)

                €
                  
              @endif


            </td>

            <td class="price">


              @if ($rate->passenger_category_name_start_value == 5)

                € {{$rate->rate}}

              @elseif ($rate->passenger_category_name_end_value <= 6)

                €
                  
              @endif

            </td>

            <td class="price">


              @if ($rate->passenger_category_name_start_value == 6)

                € {{$rate->rate}}

              @elseif ($rate->passenger_category_name_end_value <= 6)

                €
                  
              @endif          


            </td>

            <td class="price">


              @if ($rate->passenger_category_name_start_value == 7)

                € {{$rate->rate}}

              @elseif ($rate->passenger_category_name_end_value <= 7)

                €
                  
              @endif


            </td>

            <td class="price">


              @if ($rate->passenger_category_name_start_value == 8)

                € {{$rate->rate}}

              @elseif ($rate->passenger_category_name_end_value <= 9)

                €
                  
              @endif


            </td>

            <td class="price">


              @if ($rate->passenger_category_name_start_value == 9)

                € {{$rate->rate}}

              @elseif ($rate->passenger_category_name_end_value <= 10)

                €
                  
              @endif


            </td>

            <td class="price">


            @if ($rate->passenger_category_name_start_value == 10)

              € {{$rate->rate}}

            @elseif ($rate->passenger_category_name_end_value <= 11)

              €
                
            @endif

            <td class="price">


            @if ($rate->passenger_category_name_start_value == 11)

              € {{$rate->rate}}

            @elseif ($rate->passenger_category_name_end_value <= 12)

              €

            @endif


            </td>

            <td class="price">


            @if ($rate->passenger_category_name_start_value == 12)

              € {{$rate->rate}}

            @elseif ($rate->passenger_category_name_end_value <= 13)

              €
                
            @endif


            </td>

            <td class="price">


            @if ($rate->passenger_category_name_start_value == 13)

              € {{$rate->rate}}

            @elseif ($rate->passenger_category_name_end_value <= 14)

              €
                
            @endif


            </td>

            <td class="price">


            @if ($rate->passenger_category_name_start_value == 14)

              € {{$rate->rate}}

            @elseif ($rate->passenger_category_name_end_value <= 15)

              €
                
            @endif

            </td>

            <td class="price">


            @if ($rate->passenger_category_name_start_value == 15)

              € {{$rate->rate}}

            @elseif ($rate->passenger_category_name_end_value <= 16)

              €
              
            @endif


            </td>

            <td class="price">


            @if ($rate->passenger_category_name_start_value == 16)

              € {{$rate->rate}}

            @else

              €
                
            @endif


            </td>



          </tr>
          
        @endforeach
      @endforeach
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: yes now i tried your code but now the data is not passing to the table... the table is empty..